# UV texture mapping on a webpage for realistic product preview

Tags: 3d, language-agnostic, e-commerce, render, uv-mapping

I need to provide clients with a realistic preview of the product they are buying online. They select a certain fabric for, say, a shirt, and that specific pattern is projected (mapped) onto a 3D model of the shirt, so they have an idea of how the shirt will look like.

What would be a good way to do that? I hope the online game developers have a good answer to this!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the best way I have found so far is to:

1. Use a software capable of handling UV mapping (e.g. blender, maya, optitex)
2. Export photo-realistic images of your rendered 3D models in *.pgn or any other format of your choice
3. Use a sound folder stucture to store the pictures